# Node.js Lambda function not running MySQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Node.js Lambda function with the `mysql` library installed. When I run it, it doesn't execute the `query()` function, it just skips over it. Here's my code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port     : process.env.RDS_PORT
});

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  con.query("UPDATE users SET status=-1 WHERE users.id = ?", [event.params.querystring.id], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    return {
      success: true
    };
  });
  return {
    error: true,
    message: "Nothing happened"
  };
};
```

When I run this, I get the error/nothing happened result I set up. How do I get it to execute the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return-statement:

```
return {
  success: true
};
```

is NOT related to your function `handler`. Instead it is related to the anonymous function that you are defining as the "callback" to `query`. Essentially, when calling `con.query`, you are asking it to execute the query, then when it is done with it (at any point in the future), to call your callback function with the results returned and parsed from the query. After doing that your function simply returns the "negative" case.

You can change your `handler` to the following:

```
exports.handler = (event) => {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    con.query("UPDATE users SET status=-1 WHERE users.id = ?", [event.params.querystring.id], function (err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({
        success: true
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Note that on the calling side you will ned do one of the following:

1. Await the call, e.g. `var res = await handler(...)`
2. Use `then` and a callback, e.g. `handler(...).then(res => {...})`

(If you want a more concrete example of the calling side, please share the code calling you `handler` function as well).